# Advanced string formatting using conversion operators

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with the minimum field width of conversion specifiers for a class,  I have tried deleting and rewriting my last section in this the 'TD' and 'INT' but I keep getting an error on line **td = float(quaterback_stats[qb]['TD'])** the error message reads:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 24, in
>
> td = float(quaterback_stats[qb]['TD']) NameError: name 'quaterback_stats' is not defined

I am struggling to understand how this is wrongly written to produce my outcome, when I have been using quaterback_stats as my defining variable for the rest of the code. The outcome of this code is supposed to create list attaching the quarterback to their stats. Any assistance on clarification would be appreciated, hope I posted this in the proper format:

```
quarterback_stats = {
    'Aaron Rodgers': {'COMP': 371, 'YDS': 4925, 'TD': 39, 'INT': 8},
    'Peyton Manning': {'COMP': 400, 'YDS': 4659, 'TD': 37, 'INT': 11},
    'Greg McElroy': {'COMP': 19, 'YDS': 214, 'TD': 1, 'INT': 1},
    'Matt Leinart': {'COMP': 16, 'YDS': 115, 'TD': 0, 'INT': 1}
}

print('2012 quarterback statistics:')

print('  Passes completed:')
for qb in quarterback_stats:
    comp = quarterback_stats[qb]['COMP']
    print(' %s : %d' % (qb, comp))
    #print('    %?: %?' % (qb, comp))  # Replace conversion specifiers
    # Hint: Use the conversion flag '-' to left-justify names

print('  Passing yards:')
for qb in quarterback_stats:
    yds = quarterback_stats[qb]['YDS']
    print('  %s : %d' % (qb,yds))

print('  Touchdown / interception ratio:')
for qb in quarterback_stats:
    td = float(quaterback_stats[qb]['TD'])
    int = float(quaterback_stats[qb]['INT'])
    print(' %s : %.2f ' % (qb,td/int))
```

Comment: Missing the "r" in "quarterback"

Comment: wow learning to spell would be a great start, thank you for the swift reply